# Question on injective hulls

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, projective-modules, injective-modules

How can I show the following:

> Let $f: M \rightarrow N$ be a morphism in $\text{mod}(A)$, where $A$ is  an Artin algebra. Suppose $f \neq 0$. Then there exists a simple module $S$ with its injective hull $I(S)$ and a morphism $q: N \rightarrow I(S)$ such that $qf \neq 0$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please don't (a) present a statement as though it is a direct quote when it is not, as you did in the original version of the question, or (b) edit the question so that somebody's answer no longer makes sense. Downvoted for those reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain the underlined portion of Lemma 2.2.

**Lemma.**
If $h\colon A\to B$ is a nonzero module homomorphism, then there are a simple
module $S$, its injective hull $I_S$, and a map $q\colon B\to I_S$ such that $qh\neq 0$.

Apply this in the proof with $A=P_{S}$, $B=I_{S_r}/S_r$, and $h=pvf$.

*Proof of Lemma.* Since $h\neq 0$, there is some $a\in A$ such that $b:=h(a)$ is not zero. Let $C\leq B$ be a submodule of $B$ maximal for $b\notin C$. There is a least submodule of $B$ properly containing $C$, and it is $C^*=\langle C\cup \{b\}\rangle$. The natural map $\nu\colon B\to B/C$ is a surjective homomorphism onto a module $B/C$ that is an essential extension of a simple module $S:=C^*/C$. The module $B/C$ embeds into the injective hull $I_S$ of $S$; let this embedding be written $\iota\colon B/C\to I_S$. Now define $q:=\iota \nu\colon B\to I_S$. The composition $qh$ is not zero since $qh(a)=q(b)=\iota\nu(b)\neq 0$, since $\nu(b)\neq 0$ and $\iota$ is an embedding. $\Box$

Answer (score 5):

This is false:
Let $A=K[x]/(x^3)$ and $S$ the unique simple $A$-module.
The injective hull is $\pi : S \rightarrow A$ with cokernel of dimension 2 and thus not simple.

Is there an assumption missing? (it would help if you cite the article) For example it is true when $I(S)$ is also projective and $A$ has Loewy length 2.

Comment: thank you! I have added the article and highlighted the passage I am referring to.